# JScript e CSS - Rotate rodando a div ao invés de uma imagem

Tags: javascript, css, html5, drag-n-drop, rotação

Bom dia, usei uma biblioteca do JavaScript para fazer a rotação de uma imagem ao clicar nela, em um trecho do javascript eu coloquei o que irá girar quando clicar:
`$("#conteudo").rotate({`
O problema é que está girando a div inteira :( 
Como posso colocar para rodar somente o conteúdo desta div, tentei colocar assim: 
`$("#conteudo > img").rotate({` porém não deu certo :(, podem me ajudar?? 
Segue o código do projeto rodando a div inteira : 
https://gist.github.com/SoraNoKuuhaku/7aa25f3944c7a4a038c4f114cc45ca22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com o código do seu link, a imagem não esta dentro da tag com id conteúdo e sim dentro da tag com id imagem, há dois ids imagem, e você deve remover o id repetido, vamos supor que você remova o id da tag img e deixe só na div externa, você deve colocar no seu código jquery desta forma:

```
$("#imagem > img")
```

Comment: Ah sim, aí ele gira normalmente porém na div imagem, na conteúdo não estou conseguindo, vou tentar novamente removendo a img dentro da imagem, um momento !!

Comment: Pois o que quero girar na verdade, é a copia da imagem que vai para a div conteúdo entende? por isso queria colocar #conteudo > img

Comment: Consegui fazendo ` $(copyimg).rotate({`
Valeu Wictor pela ajuda !!!!

Answer (score 1):

Também poderia usar `css` em vez de `jquery` mas aí não tem `onclick`:

`#conteudo > img:hover{
        -ms-transform: rotate(7deg); /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform: rotate(7deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        transform: rotate(7deg);
    }`

Comment: Vou tentar !! Valeu pela ajuda, tenho de estudar este `:hover` pois não sei usa-lo ainda